# Any way Jsoup can parse "javascript?" data?

Tags: javascript, parsing, jsoup

Tried all but not accomplished. Here is the code:

```
public LocalTimes(City newCity) throws IOException {
        setCity(newCity);
        setDoc(Jsoup.connect("http://www.turkishairlines.com/tr-tr/ucak-bileti/" + city.getName())
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0")
                .header("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .timeout(5000)
                .post());
        Element babas = doc.getElementById("div.clock-gmt > span");
}
```

I need the value inside the tag "span" which is the gmt value of the city. As i thought that's executed via javascript i'm not able to get the text() nor the value.

Please any suggestions?

Comment: had the same problem in the past; what I did was to get the content using http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/ and after that I parse the content using jsoup; htmlunit will also run the javascript; if you think it helps I can add the code

Comment: Yes please. Maybe that can give me a go up.

Comment: can you provide a url; tried a few like but didn't work: http://www.turkishairlines.com/tr-tr/ucak-bileti/Istanbul

Comment: if you had just tried it with "istanbul" rather than "Istanbul" it was going to work. you have been trapped with the turkish characters which i have issues as well :)

Answer (score 0):

What value? span element is empty

```
<div class="clock">
    <div class="clock-day">
        Çarşamba
    </div>
    <div class="jsClock"></div>
    <div class="clock-gmt">
        GMT <span></span>
    </div>
....
```

Comment: Frankly, that's the problem. The value is not flowing down to html as it's. If it is checked via Chrome devtool it is there as it is seen on the page as well.

Comment: Hmm, I cant see this span value on page, please give full link.